# Iteration problem in permutation calculation

Tags: python, for-loop, permutation

I am trying to code an algorithm for permutation of a list. Here below my code;

```
a=30

list= []

while a<101:
    list.append(a)
    a= a+10

perm= []

for i in range(0,len(liste)):
    j=0

    if i==j:
      continue
    else:
       while j<len(liste):

           perm.append([liste[i], liste[j]])
           j=j+1
```

the output of code is like [[40, 30], [40, 40], [40, 50], [40, 60], [40, 70], [40, 80] .....
I could not figure out why [[30, 40], [30, 50], [30, 60].... results are missing and why there are still duplicate values such as [[40,40],[50,50].... Could you please help me about this?

Comment: post liste values

Comment: `list= []` -> this is a reserved word

Comment: In the 'not reinventing the wheel' category, have you looked into `permutations()` and `combinations()`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
Also, instead of adding `if i==j: continue; else: ...`, you can just skip 0 in the initial range: `range(1,len(liste))`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you code is, that you are setting `j` to `0` and than checking if `j == i` and if True you continue so you eliminate the first element in the list, that also explains why there are duplicates, you aren't checking for those

Here is a better way to do this:

```py
myList = [a * 10 for a in range(3, 11)]

perms = []

for item1 in myList:
    for item2 in myList:
        if item1 == item2:
            continue
        perms.append([item1, item2])
```

But the best way to do this would be using the [builtin itertools library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```py
from itertools import permutations

myList = [a * 10 for a in range(3, 11)]
perms = list(permutations(myList, 2))
```